# Блок меню не двигается

Tags: html, css

При практике верстки столкнулся с тем, что блок перестал реагировать на margin и padding, Так как ещё учусь могу ошибиться, но что я сделал не так.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #000000000000;
}
.logo {
 padding-top: 8%;
 display: inline-block;
}
.logo-z-index1,
.logo-z-index2 {
 font-size:  48px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-nav {
 margin-left: 95%;
 padding-top: 80%;
 display: inline;
 font-size: 32px;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#" class="logo-z-index1">P</a>
        <a href="#" class="logo-z-index2">L</a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-nav">
        <span class="menu">&#9776;</span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

По итогу "бургер-меню" просто прибило к полу блока nav [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: должно быть на одном уровне с PL

Answer (score 0):

Удалил `margin-left: 95%`, добавил `float: right`. Но легче делать с flex-box. Надеюсь помог.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.container{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #000000000000;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo-z-index1,
.logo-z-index2 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-nav {
  float: right;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#" class="logo-z-index1">P</a>
        <a href="#" class="logo-z-index2">L</a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-nav">
        <span class="menu">&#9776;</span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```